# Split lines from a file into variables (accepting spaces) BASH

Tags: linux, bash, dialog

I need a script in bash that reads a file and recognize an delimiter (";") and store the values between the delimiters into variables to build a dialog menu later.

What i've done:

```
#!/bin/bash
file="Tarefas.cfg"
nomeTarefa=''
dirOrigem=''
dirDest=''
tipoBkp=''
agendarBkp=''
compactarBkp=''
gerarLog=''
echo
for linha in $(cat $file)
do
    nomeTarefa=$(echo $linha | cut -d\; -f1 )
    dirOrigem=$(echo $linha | cut -d\; -f2 )
    dirDest=$(echo $linha | cut -d\; -f3 )
    tipoBkp=$(echo $linha | cut -d\; -f4 )
    agendarBkp=$(echo $linha | cut -d\; -f5 )
    compactarBkp=$(echo $linha | cut -d\; -f6 )
    gerarLog=$(echo $linha | cut -d\; -f7 )
    echo "$nomeTarefa $dirOrigem $dirDest $tipoBkp $agendarBkp $compactarBkp $gerarLog"
    echo
done
```

the file that it reads is :

```
Minha Tarefa;/home/;/home/;Diferencial;;N;S;
Minha Tarefa;/home/thalesg;/home/;Diferencial;;N;S;
```

And the output:

```
Minha Minha Minha Minha Minha Minha Minha

Tarefa /home/ /home/ Diferencial  N S

Minha Minha Minha Minha Minha Minha Minha

Tarefa /home/thalesg /home/ Diferencial  N S
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a `while` you can split a line into a lot of vars in 1 call.
You need to temporary change the FieldSep (IFS) into a `;`
And avoid an extra call to `cat`: do not use `cat $file | ..` but use `< $file`

```
file="Tarefas.cfg"
while IFS=";" read nomeTarefa dirOrigem dirDest tipoBkp agendarBkp compactarBkp gerarLog; do
   echo "$nomeTarefa $dirOrigem $dirDest $tipoBkp $agendarBkp $compactarBkp $gerarLog"
   echo "Show one field, the compactarBkp: $compactarBkp"
done < $file
```

Comment: Thank you very much, sir!
---edit---
When I tried with another file with more lines, it didnt show the last line, any ideas why?

Comment: Found a solution! Added || [[ -n "$line" ]] after gerarLog

Comment: @Tiaurls If you needed that then your file didn't end with a newline. Normally you only need that when you pick an alternate delimiter (like `\0`, with `-d ''`).

Comment: @Etan Reisner Actuallym, i use the echo vars >>Tarefas.cfg
I dont know how to create a new line using this, thank you anyway!

Comment: @Tiaurls You use what? `echo` adds a newline at the end of what it prints by default. So if you only ever used `echo` to write the config file then it should have had a newline at the end.